# Function to return prime numbers

Tags: r, primes

I want to write a function in R which accepts a list of integers and returns only the values which are prime.

So far I have this:

```
 primefindlist<-function(n){
 return(n[n==2 | all(n %% seq(2,ceiling(sqrt(n)),by=1) !=0)])
 }
```

But I keep getting an error message when I run the function e.g;

```
 primefindlist(c(7,11))
```

> Error in seq.default(2, ceiling(sqrt(n)), by = 1) : 
>     'to' must be of length 1

Anyone got any ideas how to overcome this?

Also the code below tells me if a single integer is prime or not ie is.prime(7) outputs TRUE

```
is.prime <- function(n) n == 2L || all(n %% 2L:ceiling(sqrt(n)) != 0)
```

Comment: you're feeding multiple arguments to `seq`'s `to` argument when it can only handle 1. Maybe try iterating or an `apply` function?

Comment: lukeA's answer works great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function is not vectorized. Try

```
primefindlist<-function(x){
  return(x[x==2 | sapply(x, function(n)all(n %% seq(2,ceiling(sqrt(n)),by=1) !=0))])
}
```

or

```
primefindlist<-function(n){
  return(n[n==2 | all(n %% seq(2,ceiling(sqrt(n)),by=1) !=0)])
}
vPrimefindlist <- Vectorize(primefindlist, vectorize.args = "n")
vPrimefindlist(c(7,11))
```

Comment: Hey Luke, you know in your first answer above if there a way of not writing    function(n)all(n %% seq(2,ceiling(sqrt(n)),by=1) !=0     and instead calling that function a name and using the name in the sapply part ?

Comment: Sure. `primefindlist<-function(x){ f <- function(n)all(n %% seq(2,ceiling(sqrt(n)),by=1) !=0); return(x[x==2 | sapply(x, f)]) }` should work, too.

Answer (score 1):

How about using `isprime` from the `gmp` library?

```
myPrimes <- function(x) {x[which(isprime(x)>0)]}
```

Here are some tests:

```
set.seed(33)
randSamp <- sample(10^6,10^5)

system.time(t1 <- myPrimes(randSamp))
user  system elapsed 
0.07    0.00    0.08 

system.time(t2 <- primefindlist(randSamp))
user  system elapsed 
7.04    0.00    7.06 

all(t1==t2)
[1] TRUE
```

If you are interested, the `isprime` function implements the [Miller-Rabin primality test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miller%E2%80%93Rabin_primality_test).  It is fairly easy to write this algorithm yourself if you are determined to not use any external libraries. [Rosetta Code](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Miller%E2%80%93Rabin_primality_test) is a good place to start (there currently isn't an R implementation yet).